# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'x', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'x'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have added a drop down list to match the school contact to the school when creating a new exam for a student of that school.  The problem is when I try to post I get the error.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Data.members_exams', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'NAHPapp.Models.DropDownList'.

I know that I should be passing in different model from what the error reads however I can't pin point where to change at.  The goal is to be able to save with the post.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult DropDownListCreate()
    {

        List<SelectListItem> schoolsId = new List<SelectListItem>();
        DropDownList DropDownList = new DropDownList();

        List<school> sch = db.schools.OrderBy(x => x.schools_name).ToList();
        sch.ForEach(x =>
        {
            schoolsId.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.schools_name, Value = x.schools_id.ToString() });
        });
        DropDownList.schools_id = schoolsId;


        ViewBag.schools_contacts = new SelectList(db.schools, "schools_contacts_id", "schools_contact_firstname");

        ViewBag.exams_id = new SelectList(db.exams, "exams_id", "exams_description");
        ViewBag.members_exams_status_id = new SelectList(db.members_exams_status, "members_exams_status_id", "members_exams_status_description");
        ViewBag.members_exams_types_id = new SelectList(db.members_exams_types, "members_exams_types_id", "members_exams_types_description");
        ViewBag.schools_id = new SelectList(db.schools.OrderBy(x => x.schools_name), "schools_id", "schools_name");


        return View(DropDownList);
    }


    public ActionResult Contact(string schools_id)
    {
        int schoolID;
        List<SelectListItem> schoolsName = new List<SelectListItem>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(schools_id))
        {
            schoolID = Convert.ToInt32(schools_id);
            List<schools_contacts> Name = db.schools_contacts.Where(x => x.schools_id == schoolID).ToList();
            Name.ForEach(x =>
            {
                schoolsName.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.schools_contacts_firstname + " " + x.schools_contacts_lastname + " | " + x.schools_contacts_email, Value = x.schools_contacts_id.ToString() });
            });
        }
        return Json(schoolsName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DropDownListCreate([Bind(Include = "members_exams_id,members_id,schools_id,exams_id,members_exams_status_id,members_exams_types_id,members_exams_username,members_exams_password,members_exams_firstname,members_exams_middlename,members_exams_lastname,members_exams_ssn,members_exams_email,members_exams_expirationdate,members_exams_examdate,members_exams_session,members_exams_score,members_exams_startdate,members_exams_address,members_exams_city,members_exams_state,members_exams_zip,members_exams_phone,members_exams_testinglocation,members_exams_proctorname,members_exams_application,members_exams_payment,members_exams_diploma,members_exams_processing")] members_exams members_exams)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.members_exams.Add(members_exams);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", "members", new { id = members_exams.members_id });  //custom route to go to details of student.
        }

        ViewBag.exams_id = new SelectList(db.exams, "exams_id", "exams_description", members_exams.exams_id);
        ViewBag.members_exams_status_id = new SelectList(db.members_exams_status, "members_exams_status_id", "members_exams_status_description", members_exams.members_exams_status_id);
        ViewBag.members_exams_types_id = new SelectList(db.members_exams_types, "members_exams_types_id", "members_exams_types_description", members_exams.members_exams_types_id);
        ViewBag.schools_id = new SelectList(db.schools, "schools_id", "schools_name", members_exams.schools_id);


        return View(members_exams);
    }
```

View:

```
@using Data;
@model NAHPapp.Models.DropDownList

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.schools_id, "School Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.schools_id, Model.schools_id, "----Select----", new { @id = "ddlSchool" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.schools_id, "Proctor Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div id="Name" class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.schools_contacts_firstname, new List<SelectListItem>(), "--Select--", new { @id = "ddlName" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.exams_id, "Exams Id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.DropDownList("exams_id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.exams_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" /> |
            @Html.ActionLink("Member Index", "Index", "members", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddlSchool').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/DropDownList/GetContact",
            data: { schools_id: $('#ddlSchool').val() },
            datatype: "json",
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                var Name = "<select id='ddlName'>";
                Name = Name + '<option value="">--Select--</option>';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    Name = Name + '<option value=' + data[i].Value + '>' + data[i].Text + '</option>';
                }
                Name = Name + '</select>';
                $('#Name').html(Name);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Any help or guidance would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this line in your HttpPost action method.

> return View(members_exams)

In your HttpPost `DropDownListCreate` action method, If model state is not valid, you are returning an object of `members_exams` class. But your view is strongly typed to `DropDownList` type. (*In your GET action you are sending the correct object*)

You should make sure you are returning an object of same type (like you did in your GET action).

So replace

```
return View(members_exams);
```

With the below code (*I copied it from your GET action method*)

```
 DropDownList DropDownList = new DropDownList();
 List<school> sch = db.schools.OrderBy(x => x.schools_name).ToList();
 sch.ForEach(x =>
    {
        schoolsId.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.schools_name, Value = x.schools_id.ToString() });
    });
 DropDownList.schools_id = schoolsId;
 return View(DropDownList);
```

While this will fix your current error about non matching types, Your view is going to be displayed like your initial GET view ! I suggest you take a moment and create a common view model which you can send to your view from both your GET action and POST action (When `ModelState.IsValid` is `false`)